# Do not display the list of the most viewed articles in the template

Tags: python, html, django

I want the article to appear first and then the article on the number of views.
I make a list of the most popular articles on the site and so that the list of articles is displayed next to each other in order but for some reason they are not displayed in the template .
I have a view model and articles should be sorted by it the more views

views.py

```
class ArticleIndex(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def article_tops(self):
        article_top = Articles.objects.all().order_by('-view')
        return {'article_top':article_top}
```

posts.html

```
   {% for article in object_list %}

    <h1> {{ article_top }} </h1>

    {%  endfor %}
```

Comment: Why do you think this should work? What is supposed to be calling the `article_tops` method?

Answer (score 1):

What you here should do is set this as *queryset*, like:

```
class ArticleIndex(ListView):
    model = Articles
    queryset = Articles.objects.all().order_by('-view')
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'
    paginate_by = 6
```

The template than looks like:

```
{% for article in object_list %}
    <h1> {{ article }} </h1>
{%  endfor %}
```